# how to add new R packages in azure machine learning for time series anomaly detection

Tags: r, azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to find out time series anomaly detection in which i need to install new R packages. In this i m following https://github.com/business-science/anomalize site. In this i needed to install 2 packages: `tidyverse` and `anomalize`.

1. can anyone help me on installing package mentioned above as I am getting

   > error "package or namespace load failed for tidyverse"
2. Also while adding zip of `tidyverse` and `anomalize` do I need to add any other packages and dependencies in that as I am adding only those 2 packages thinking there r no other dependencies I needed for those 2?

you can see in code that I created `R_Package.zip` and put `tidyverse.zip` and `anomalize.zip` in that that

```
dataset1 <- maml.mapInputPort(1)
data.set <- data.frame(installed.packages())
#install.packages(“src/R_Package/tidyverse_1.2.1.zip”, lib = “.”, 
                  repos = NULL, verbose = TRUE);
#library(tidyverse, lib.loc=”.”, verbose=TRUE);

install.packages("src/tidyverse.zip",lib=".",repos=NULL,verbose=TRUE)
library(R_package, lib.loc = ".", verbose=TRUE);

install.packages("src/anomalize.zip",lib=".",repos=NULL,verbose=TRUE)
library(R_package, lib.loc = ".", verbose=TRUE);

#success <- library("tidyverse", lib.loc = ".", 
                    logical.return = TRUE, verbose = TRUE)
#library(tidyverse)


maml.mapOutputPort("dataset1");
```

Comment: Answer not helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the error message, notice that it may take some time for the installed packages to become actually available; quoting from [Adding R Packages In Azure ML](https://blog.tallan.com/2016/12/27/adding-r-packages-in-azure-ml/) blog post:

> Note: In one instance, we ran into an issue where the package was not
>   loaded into the workspace immediately. We had to wait about half an
>   hour before we could use the package. You may be running into this
>   issue as well if you see a message that looks something like this
>   [image]
>
> and you’ve used the above method to check which packages are in your
>   workspace and the package in question appears on that list. If this is
>   the case, we suggest waiting a bit before running your experiment
>   again.

AFAIK yes, you also need to add the package dependencies; the SO thread [Install R Packages in Azure ML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43176442/install-r-packages-in-azure-ml) contains some useful hints.