# How to install some R packages in Azure ML

Tags: r, azure, installation, package, azure-machine-learning-service

I need to install some R packages in AzureML, but I think that I´m not doing this by the correct way:

```
install.packages(c (
  
  "timetk",
  "modeltime",
  "modeltime.ensemble",
  "quantmod",
  "rvest",
  "tidyverse",
  "gtrendsR",
  "xlsx" 
))
```

Then when I call the librarys after installing I have the following issue message:

```
Error in library(timetk): There is no package called `timetk´...
```

I readed this post here ([Install R Packages in Azure ML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43176442/install-r-packages-in-azure-ml)) in stackoverflow but I confess that I can´t go ahead to solve this...

Comment: If you are trying to load a package before it's been installed, as you said "I call the libraries before installing", then of course R cannot find the package. 

I ran your above code to install those packages.  Once you run that, you will not need to re-run it, just use the ```library()```function to open the desired library

Comment: May be worth looking at `pacman` package for installation and loading of multiple packages in one call.

Comment: You need to install the package before calling.
Please refer [R Error in library](https://statisticsglobe.com/r-error-library-there-is-no-package-called)

Answer (score 0):

> Error in library(timetk): There is no package called `timetk

- The reason for this is that you have not installed the timetk package before loading it.
- In case the timetk package is not installed yet, we have to apply the install packages function first:

  ***install.packages("timetk ")   # Install timetk***

Note that you have to install a package only once.

Now, we can apply the library function to load the timetk package
library("timetk ")            # Load timetk